# Select from a table where column row has Zero (0) or Zeros (000000)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How do I select from a table column row where only the result set should contain a table column rows where there are Zero(0) or Zeros(00000) and Not any other. e.g from the table below: i want rows 1,3 and 5 to be returned because they contains Zero(s) as account number. I don't need rows like 2 and 4 to be returned.

Sample data is as below:

```
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+------------------+---------------+------------+
|  Id   | IdGrower | IdBank | IdBankBranch |  TxtAccountName  | TxtAccountNr  | FlgPayBank |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1     |    11296 |      9 |            9 | FEDNARY MANGWIRO |000000000000   | No         |
| 2     |      617 |      4 |            4 | SIPIWE MAGADZIRE |10519000000000 | No         |
| 3     |    54272 |      6 |            6 | Obert Mudzingwa  |0              | No         |
| 4     |   5473   |      4 |            4 | Bin              |051            | No         |
| 5     |  7463    |      6 |            6 | Bob              |000            | No         |
+-------+----------+--------+--------------+------------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Dears, i have edited my question for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like, if your acctno has empty strings you will need to elaborate this query a bit

```
create table #t (name varchar(20), acctno varchar(30))

insert #t values ('Tim', '000')
insert #t values ('Jim', '00750')
insert #t values ('Bim', '0000000')

select * from #t where replace(acctno, '0','') = ''
```

Comment: To handle empty strings, something like: `select * from #t where len(replace(acctno, '0','')) = 0 and len(acctno) > 0` can be used

Comment: Thanks, it worked.